# ¿Por qué marca error en la promesa?

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con **service workers** para generar push notification, estoy siguiendo el ejemplo de google del siguiente enlace:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user

Pero al solicitar el permiso me marca este error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Notification.requestPermission is not a function

El codigo es el mismo que en  el ejemplo:

```
function askPermission() {

console.log(Notification);
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
const permissionResult = Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
  resolve(result);
});

 if (permissionResult) {
  permissionResult.then(resolve, reject);
 }
 }).then(function(permissionResult) {
if (permissionResult !== 'granted') {
  throw new Error('We weren\'t granted permission.');
}
  });
}
```

Comment: Por casualidad revisaste la compatibilidad de browsers para esa api? La puedes ver aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission

Comment: Notification no tiene requestPermission... qué browser estás usuando? en chrome sí está disponible. Notification.requestPermission
ƒ () { [native code] }